# How to make Solr's spell checker ignore case?

Tags: solr, spell-checking

How do you ask the example spellchecker to ignore case ?
I am using all defaults shown in the [demo](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Spell_Checking_Analysis).
Now I see that if I type *Ancient*, it asks "did you mean *ancient* ? "  What do I do ?

ps : I don't have anything that has the word "spell" in my schema.xml!!!! How is it working ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The schema should have a field type called "spell" that is used for spell checking. This will lowercase all words used by the spellchecker so you don't have to worry about case. Here is an example of how to use this field type.

Create a field in your schema for spell checking.

```
<field name="spelling" type="spell" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

And then use a copy field to copy data into this field. The example, the code below will copy the "product_name" field into the spell checker.

```
<copyField source="product_name" dest="spelling"/>
```

**Edit...**

Sorry... I though the "spell" field type was in the default schema. Add this to your schema in the same section as the other fieldType tags.

```
<fieldType name="spell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
        words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" 
        ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
        words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: +1 for this — copy your text data into a text field used to train the spell checker. We do something similar with our default config over at [Websolr](http://websolr.com) by using a `copyField` to copy all fields named `*_text` into a text column named `textSpell`. See the [blog post](http://blog.websolr.com/post/2748574298/spellcheck-with-solr-spellcheckcomponent) that I wrote up on it.

Comment: But again, How is it _already working fine_ without anything remotely related to spell checker in my "schema.xml" ?

Comment: The "spell" field type is not required to use the spell checker, but it processes the data in a way that is ideal for spell checking. This should solve the problem in your original question by passing everything through a lower case filter.

Comment: @Nick C. If I add the things mentioned above, it stops working... :(

Comment: I'm guessing that you may not have put the <fieldType> tags in the proper section of the schema, but you'll need to look at the error log see what is causing it to fail. Also, make sure you stop Solr, remove the existing index, and then restart Solr when you make a changes like this. The old index is no longer valid and needs to be re-built.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your solrconfig.xml - I think that will provide a clue.

My best guess will be that solrconfig.xml contains the config for the spellchecker ([link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Configuration)) which specifies the field to be used for generating spelling suggestions. That field does not have a LowerCaseFilter in your schema.xml

Comment: here : [link](http://cid-230da956ce9fd436.office.live.com/self.aspx/StackOverflow/solrconfig.xml)

Comment: You have a **text** field which is being used for spellchecking. Either ensure that this field is passed through a lower case filter (you will need to modify schema.xml), or create a separate spellcheck field as suggested by Nick C in a different answer to this question.