# Case insensitive spell check in Solr

Tags: solr, spell-checking, case-insensitive, lowercase

How can we make spellchecker in solr to ignore case? For the query : "Lether", I get suggestion "leather" which is right. But if the query is "lether", I get some different suggestion like "lethel" which is not correct.

I tried the configuration as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151607/how-to-make-solrs-spell-checker-ignore-case/5158554#5158554), but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have copied my configuration here for the reference:

```
<fieldType name="text_spell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
     <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="spelltext" type="text_spell" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="spelltext" />
```

Is there any obvious thing that I am missing?

Comment: Hey, You got the solution of your answer. I stuck in the same condition. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In cse you haven't already, in your `spellchecker` component you must specify a `fieldType` using a lower case filter, e.g.,

```
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">spell</str>
  <str name="field">text_spell</str>
  <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spell</str>
  <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
</lst>
```

Secondly, also notice the `buildOnOptimize` which rebuilds your spellcheck index on the `optimize` command.

Comment: Yes, I am already doing that. Here is my configuration that I am using which is not working:       inline `<lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">spelltext</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellchecker</str>
      <str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>
      <str name="accuracy">0.8</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>`

Comment: any luck with this one?